# Massive Dynamic theme Cart page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image is attached for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mvM5.png)

I am creating e-commerce website with massive dynamic theme. Everything was going good but when i clicked on the cart button on the main screen, a popup screen appears which shows the cart items and view cart and checkout buttons at the bottom of the page. I am not able to click these buttons as these are overlapped by collapse button. Also, I am unable to change the logo of this page. I cannot find the way to solve this problem in the documentation as well.

[edit] This is known as notification center in massive dynamic theme. I am able to change the logo here but cannot solve the overlapping problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not attach the image in weblink, instead, attach the image to the body of the question.

Comment: How can I attach the image to the body of the question? To make it more clear for the people who are answering it

Comment: When you edit the question there is small icon option call image, <ctrl + G>, use that to attach the image to the question body.

Comment: I have attached the image in this manner. Still it is not showing as I need 10 reputation points to directly attach an image.